# NGINX http://example.com to https://www.example.com rewrite, how?

Tags: ssl, nginx, url-rewriting

I have recently bought an SSL certificate that I want to try out. I have also created an VPS server for the first time and after many struggles and angry management I have succeeded in installing a LEMP and NGINX on Ubuntu 14.04 and also installing an SSL certificate. My website is [wknet.se](http://wknet.se).

Now, I want to rewrite url's:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
|             From                 |              To           |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|   http://wknet.se                |   https://www.wknet.se    |
|   http://wknet.se/index.php      |   https://www.wknet.se    |
|   http://www.wknet.se/index.php  |   https://www.wknet.se    |
|   wknet.se                       |   https://www.wknet.se    |
|   wknet.se/index.php             |   https://www.wknet.se    |
|   www.wknet.se/index.php         |   https://www.wknet.se    |
|   https://wknet.se               |   https://www.wknet.se    |
|   https://wknet.se/index.php     |   https://www.wknet.se    |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

After many trials and errors and several devastating hours I have only 2 rewrites left to fix:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
|             From                 |              To           |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|   https://wknet.se               |   https://www.wknet.se    |
|   https://wknet.se/index.php     |   https://www.wknet.se    |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, I do not know how to fix them! I have googled and googled and I have tested several good rewrite rules for NGINX but I have not figured it out yet.

This is my first time I am working on SSL, Rewrite rules etc on NGINX.

Now, this is how my server settings look like for [wknet.se](http://wknet.se):

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

   add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
   return 301 https://www.wknet.se$request_uri; 
}
server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name www.wknet.se;

   root /var/www/wknet.se/html;
   index index.php index.html index.htm;

   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/SSL.CRT;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/KEY.KEY;

   ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_ciphers ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

   error_page 404 /404.html;
   error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

   location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }

   location = /50x.html {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
   }
   location = /index {
      rewrite ^/index\.(php)$ https://www.wknet.se/ permanent;
   }

   location ~ /\.ht {
      deny all;
   }

   location = /favicon.ico {
      log_not_found off;
      access_log off;
   }

   location = /robots.txt {
      allow all;
      log_not_found off;
      access_log off;
   }

   location ~ /\. { 
      deny all; 
      error_log off; 
      log_not_found off; 
   }

   location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
      log_not_found off;
      expires 365d;
   }

   location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
      access_log off;
      log_not_found off;
      expires max;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
   }

   location ~* \.(7z|ai|class|css|csv|ejs|eps|flv|html?|jar|jpe?g|js|json|lzh|m4a|m4v|mov|mp3|pdf|pict|pls|ps|psd|swf|tiff?|txt|webp)$ {
      access_log off; 
      log_not_found off;
      expires max;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
   }
}
```

If anyone could help me with this I would be really happy! Also if someone has tips on my server settings to make some improvements it would help alot also because I do not know if I have done it correctly!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect from *example.com* to *www.example.com* you just need to create a separate server block and set the *server_name* accordingly. In your setup, you would do:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name wknet.se;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/SSL.CRT;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/KEY.KEY;

    # OBSOLETE:
    # ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    # ssl_ciphers ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM;

    # Use currently secure protocols
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4';

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    return 301 https://www.wknet.se$request_uri;
}
```

The above will redirect all *https://wknet.se/...* requests to *https://www.wknet.se/...*.

For *https* you need to include the ssl certificate keys within the block (or you can set the ssl cert. statements in your *http* block if all your servers are using the same set).

**Additonal Configurations**

If you want to redirect *http://wknet.se/...* to *http://www.wknet.se/...* -- normal http requests to ssl https requests -- add an additional server block that listens on port 80 and redirects to port 443:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.wknet.se wknet.se;
    return 301 https://www.wknet.se$request_uri;
}
```

The above will redirect *http://wknet.se/...* and any requests for subdomains like *http://www.wknet.se/...* or *http://static.wknet.se/...*, etc. to *https://www.wknet.se/...*.

**2015-03-28 Revision Note**

- Updated example code to use secure SSL protocols. The original example uses SSLv3 which is deprecated. I replaced the `ssl_protocols` and `ssl_ciphers` with more secure settings according to current practice.

Comment: Thank you very much for that @kchan it worked perfectly :) It redirects smoothly. 

I copied everything and changed it to fit my needs and I copied it also to my other site I have also on the server. But the problem there is that it redirects to the defualt server all the time. 

The only links that work are [https://www.webkreativ.hr](https://www.webkreativ.hr) and [https://webkreativ.hr](https://webkreativ.hr).

If you type in webkreativ.hr or [www.webkreativ.hr](http://www.webkreativ.hr) you will be redirected to [https://www.wknet.se](https://www.wknet.se). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should have a default server block that's a "catchall" for all requests. Usually you would set the *server_name* to *_* and in that block you can redirect all requests to whatever url you want. I would check your server nginx configs to see what the default server block redirects to. See the nginx docs for examples of the "catch-all" server block: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: Here you can see the settings of --> [nginx.conf](https://www.wknet.se/nginx/nginx.conf.txt). Here you can see the settings of --> [wknet.se](https://www.wknet.se/nginx/wknet.se.txt). Here you can see the settings of --> [webkreativ.hr](https://www.wknet.se/nginx/webkreativ.hr.txt). I would be really happy if you could help me further with it.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what domains you want to redirect to what, but I added an additional example in the answer that redirects port 80 http requests to https requests on 443. See if that answers your questions.

Comment: Usually i add 2 more parts to preserve the query string while redirecting `return 301 https://www.wknet.se$request_uri$is_args$query_string;`

Comment: The problem is that [webkreativ.hr](http://webkreativ.hr) and [www.webkreativ.hr](http://www.webkreativ.hr) redirect to [https://www.wknet.se](https://www.wknet.se). I want them to redirect to correct domain --> [https://www.webkreativ.hr](https://www.webkreativ.hr). How do I manage that?

Comment: @damircalusic: You need just to create a server block to redirect "webkreativ.hr" and "www.webkreativ.hr" port 80 requests to "https://www.webkreativ.hr" (ssl request on port 443). uUse the added server block example in the answer and change the domain names accordingly.

Comment: @Mohammad AbuShady: I believe "$request_uri" already includes args (query string parameters).

Comment: @kchan it does not work... I have restarted NGINX and it still redirects to wrong domain. the code --> server { listen 80; add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000; return 301 https://www.webkreativ.hr$request_uri; }

Comment: @damircalusic: Does your block have "server_name webkreativ.hr *. webkreativ.hr;"? If not, you probably need to add that.

Comment: Thank you! It works now really good. :) It had to be a server name as you said @kchan. Thank you. :)

Comment: @kchan http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri apparently yes, didn't know that